# Exception: argument too large: value Google Script

Tags: caching, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, urlfetch

I'm trying to **scrape** a website & put the value in cache so I don't hit the daily limit of UrlFetchApp

Here is the script I did:

```
/**
 * Scrape URL, return whatever you choose with jquery-style selectors. 
 Dependency: cheeriogs, see https://github.com/fgborges/cheeriogs
 *
 * @param {url} valid start-url
 * @return result (array values)
 *
 * @customfunction
 */
function scrapercache(url) {
    var result = [];
    var description;
    var options = {
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'followRedirects': false,
    };
  
var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

try {  
  let res = cache.get(url);

  if (!res) {
    // trim url to prevent (rare) errors
    url.toString().trim();
    var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var c = r.getResponseCode();

    // check for meta refresh if 200 ok
    if (c == 200) {
      var html = r.getContentText();
      cache.put(url, "cached", 21600);
      properties.setProperty(url, html);

      var $ = Cheerio.load(html); // make sure this lib is added to your project!

      // meta description
      if ($('meta[name=description]').attr("content")) {
        description = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content").trim();
      }
    }
  
    result.push([description]);    
  }
} 
catch (error) {
  result.push(error.toString());
} 
finally {
  return result;
}
 
}
```

but when I call the function like that:

```
=scrapercache("https://www.gurufocus.com/term/total_freecashflow/nyse:ABBV/Free-Cash-Flow")
```

I get the error message:

```
Exception: argument too large: value
```

Anyone can help me please?
Thank you :)
Gabriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the [official  documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putkey,-value,-expirationinseconds),

> The maximum length of a key is 250 characters. The maximum amount of data that can be stored per key is 100KB.

If the  size of the data put in cache exceeds any of the above limitations, the error

> Exception: argument too large

is shown. In your case, `value` exceeds 100KB.  Solution would be to cache only necessary data or don't cache at all depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster,
thanks for your quick response.
Ok, I understand.

How can I limit I only want the first 40 characters of "description" please?

I tried to apply it after I call the function with a LEFT(function, 40) but it looks like I need to cut the value directly in the function itself not after calling it.

I found some stuff about substr but I don't know how to use it in my code.
Could you help me to reduce the result of this function to not hit the argument size limit please?

Sorry, I'm very new to coding.
Thanks again

Comment: @Gabriel Ask a new question with your attempts on  string methods like substr, slice  and [mcve].

Comment: Hi @TheMaster, I modified the code adding substr like that:

// meta description
      if ($('meta[name=description]').attr("content")) {
        description = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content").trim();
        var trim_des = description.substr(0, 40);
      }
    }
  
    result.push([trim_des]);    
  }
} 
catch (error) {
  result.push(error.toString());
} 
finally {
  return result;
}

I can't test now because I reached daily urlFetch limit, so I have to wait few more hours but I hope I use it correctly.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Hi TheMaster,
I just tried the new script but I can the following error: Reference does not exist.
Here is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911833/error-reference-does-not-exist-google-script
Thanks again

Comment: 100KB is too small. A JSON string generated by some random APIs can large than that!

Comment: @TRX You can store each key of that json separately. Number of keys that can be stored is 1000. @100k/key, you can store 100,000kb or 100MB